# Create regex which check number and dot. For e.g.: 1.1.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

For e.g.: 1.1.1.1, 123.52.25.252

Comment: Hello and welcome. It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @Ravi g welcome to the StackOverflow. First, you try by yourself what you want if you unable to do and facing any issue then post your question with some code what you have tried. `Create regex which check number and dot. For e.g.: 1.1.1.1
` what is this mean

Comment: Are you wanting a regex for IP addresses? If so, they're already around, and just a quick google search away.

Comment: If you asking how to see how many numbers and dots their are you in that string you could do something like: `"1.1.1.1, 123.52.25.252".match(/\.|\d/g).length`

Comment: Try this regex
([0-9])+(([.])+([0-9]){1,3}){3,3}

Comment: @Ravi g ^[0-9]{1,2}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$

Answer (score 0):

try this regex
/([0-9])+(([.])+([0-9]){1,3}){3,3}/g